# UE4 - Can anyone explain how I might recreate this material from a photo?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I know this is not a natural question to ask about on StackOverflow and I am also aware there are forums for this kind of thing elsewhere but this is honestly my last hope so please bear with me here.

[image]

As far as I can tell it might be emissive but it has too much of a reflective surface for that to be the case, and it also has a differently colored reflection to normal reflections from the environment.

Just so you know, the environment's sun and reflections do not naturally look this deep a yellow, in fact it looks pretty natural, unlike this material.

I have tried remaking it by creating some kind of gold metal look but it looks like the thing I am missing is the custom color to the reflections and possibly some different kind of reflective node.

All I hope to see is someone tell me how this might be done in c++ or UE4's material editor as I really really like the look of this and would love to use it inside of a game of mine that I am working on!

Comment: I think this might be more appropriate to ask somewhere like the blender stack exchange https://blender.stackexchange.com to ask what kind of features a material like this would have

Comment: Fiddling around with an old blender version I have I think I have something similar when I turn on anisotropic shading / tangent shading, and have some emission on it too.